# Image compression via SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, image-processing, compression

Let $A$ be an image of size $m \times n$. Its SVD is $A = U\Sigma V^T$.
Equivalently, 
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i u_iv_i^T,
$$
where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the $i$-th column of $U$ and $V$, respectively
and $\sigma_i$ is the $i$-th largest singular value of $A$.

When we compress this image $A$ using SVD, we typically need to store 
$\{\sigma_j, u_j, v_j\}_{j=1}^{k}$ for some $k < \min\{n,m\}$.
Thus, we need memory to store $k(1+m+n)$ entries.
However, the whole image has $mn$ entries.
Hence, if
$$
k > \frac{mn}{1+m+n},
$$
it seems to me that we do not compress the image, rather we are wasting our memory.

I am wondering if I misunderstood the concept of the image compression or it is typically the case where $k$ is extremely small.

Any comments/answers/suggestions will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your description is correct. 
Note that, when $m = n$, the condition becomes $k > n^2/(2n+1)$ or roughly $k > n/2$.
So if the singular values do not decay fast enough, you are correct that there is no gain (with that approach).

Comment: @user7440 Thanks for your comment. It's very helpful. If you don't mind, could you guide me to some references so that I could look up what other approaches exist and (hopefully I could understand) why they are better than SVD?

Comment: I do not know references for this field. Here is a good lecture though https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-31-change-of-basis-image-compression/

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/239729/116107 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/13614886/6338725 and

Comment: This would only be true if it were a grayscale image I believe.